# Why is struct consumed when using self but not when deconsturcting?

Tags: rust

I started learning rust from https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/, and as far as I understand rust uses move on an assignment, and you explicitly have to tell it to copy with `clone()`.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

impl Point {
    fn destroy(self) {
        let Point{x, y} = self;
        println!("pt is consumed: {}, {}", x, y);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let pt = Point{x: 2f32, y: 2f32};
    let Point{x, y} = pt; //#a
    println!("destructured, pt not consumed: {}, {}", x, y);
    let pt2 = pt; //#b
    //println!("pt is consumed: {:?}", pt);
    pt2.destroy(); //#c
    //println!("pt2 is consumed: {:?}", pt2);
}
```

So pt is consumed on `#b`, that is clear why. But why is it consumed on `#c` when it's not consumed on `#a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `f32` implement `Copy` the assignment at #a which could also be written as

```rust
let x = pt.x;
let y = pt.y;
```

performs 2 implicit copies of the two float values and thus doesn't move `pt`.

But `Point::destroy()` takes ownership of the `Point` (by using `self` instead of `&self`) and thus moves the `Point` into it's body.
What it does inside of the function is irrelevant (i.e. you can still use `self` after `let Point{ x, y } = self;` but not `pt2` after `pt2.destroy()`).

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that, when destructuring the structure, we semantically move its fields out of it one-by-one. But in your case the fields are `Copy`, so they're copied, not moved, and the struct remains intact.

If you tried with something that's non-`Copy`, like `String`, you get the expected error:

```
error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `pt`
  --> src/main.rs:18:15
   |
16 |     let Point{x, y} = pt; //#a
   |                  - value partially moved here
17 |     println!("destructured, pt not consumed: {}, {}", x, y);
18 |     let pt2 = pt; //#b
   |               ^^ value used here after partial move
   |
   = note: partial move occurs because `pt.y` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1dbd839c03fff1eea81f9f85c4f134a7)